# Unresolved package import in OSGi

Tags: java, osgi, bnd

In my Bnd (OSGi) project, I keep getting the following error whenever I try to run a bundle *(called **UI** in this case)*, even though I have the dependency jar *(org.apache.commons.io)* correctly installed.

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle ui [12]: Unable to resolve 12.2: missing requirement [12.2] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.commons.io)(version>=2.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
```

I have tried using other **org.apache.commons.io** releases, but to no success.

**The UI Bnd.bnd file**

```
Bundle-Version: 0.0.0.${tstamp}
-buildpath: \
    ../cnf/plugins/org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.annotation-3.2.0.jar;version=file,\
    org.apache.felix.dependencymanager,\
    osgi.core,\
    launcher;version=latest,\
    org.apache.commons.io
Private-Package: \
    ui.impl,\
    resources.css,\
    resources.images
Export-Package: ui
Import-Package: *
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Do you have the bundle exporting the package installed to be resolved when you run your bundle?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @BJ Hargrave I've tried adding `-runrequires: osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.apache.commons.io)'` to the Bnd.bnd file, but that doesn't resolve the problem. I still get the same error

Comment: That doesn't answer BJ's question. Is the org.apache.commons.io bundle in the resolved state?

Comment: @Neil Bartlett It is in **Installed** state

Comment: So that's a no. There may be a missing dependency which prevents the commons.io bundle from resolving. What happens when you try to start that bundle?

Comment: @Neil Bartlett  `g! start 12` outouts 
`org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle ui [12]: Unable to resolve 12.0: missing requirement [12.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.commons.io)(version>=2.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))`

Comment: You're saying that `org.apache.commons.io` doesn't start because it depends on `org.apache.commons.io`? Or maybe we're talking about different bundles... what is the name of bundle ID 12?

Comment: 12 is called **UI**. UI is dependent on org.apache.commons.io

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107999/discussion-between-program-me-rev-and-neil-bartlett).

Comment: So like I said, please try to start the bundle named **org.apache.commons.io** and report back.

Comment: If you use org.apache.commons.* bundles, almost all bundles import the package org.apache.commons.logging. You can provide it either from the Apache logging bundle (named like the package) or from jcl.over.slf4j or whatever implermentation you like.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? If so what was the solution?

Comment: @Neil Bartlett I downloaded **Amdatu** from **Eclipse Marketplace**, and called the dependency from the Amdatu repository suite, from the **Amdatu Dependencies** group in particular. For some reason this dependency worked. I, hewever, bet that there's a better, proper fix out there that should set a depency to work irrespective. I don't think I really solved the problem here. Just avoided it, and I'm afraid I might come accross it again soon enough. This, however, works for now.

Comment: I believe that if you had provided the information I requested, then I would have been able to help to fix it. Missing dependencies are simple to resolve, you just have to work out where to get the package you need.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded **Amdatu** from **Eclipse Marketplace**, and called the dependency from the Amdatu repository suite, from the **Amdatu Dependencies** group in particular. For some reason this dependency worked.

I, hewever, bet that there's a better, proper fix out there that should set a depency to work irrespective. I don't think I really solved the problem here. Just avoided it, and I'm afraid I might come accross it again soon enough. This, however, works for now.